# In Google Datastore, is it possible to get the cursor for a specific item?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

It is possible to use [Datastore.key](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#assigning_identifiers) to generate a new key for an element:

```
const taskKey = datastore.key(['Task', 'sampleTask']);
```

When running a query, we may get an [endCursor](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#cursors_limits_and_offsets) that can be used to get the next results.

The cursor is some base64 encoded token that contains the project ID, kind, and key of the last element fetched, with a little bit of unknown binary data.

Would there be a way/method to get that base64 cursor value given the key of an item and kind+project ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Or I should rather say that it doesn't make much sense to (attempt to) obtain a cursor from an entity by itself because a cursor only has meaning in the context of the original query from which it was obtained. From [Limitations of cursors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/query-cursors#limitations_of_cursors) (emphasis mine):

> Cursors are subject to the following limitations:
>
> - A cursor can be used only by the same application that performed the original query, and only to continue the same query. To use the cursor
>     in a subsequent retrieval operation, you must reconstitute the
>     original query exactly, including the same entity kind, ancestor
>     filter, property filters, and sort orders. **It is not possible** to
>     retrieve results using a cursor without setting up the same query from
>     which it was originally generated.

Also from [Cursors and data updates](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/query-cursors#cursors_and_data_updates):

> The cursor's position is defined as the location in the result list
>   after the last result returned. A cursor is not a relative position in
>   the list (it's not an offset); it's a marker to which Cloud Datastore
>   can jump when starting an index scan for results.

Comment: Do you know it's not possible for sure or are you trying to argue that it doesn't make sense? It makes sense to me to have a way to be able to infer a cursor value from an entry. That's what dynamodb does and it's pretty useful.

Comment: Both, in the particular datastore context. There was a post which I can't locate with someone actually attempting to do that, based on a similar (or the same?) observation. The quotes, I believe, clarify that what you desire/expect is not possible with the datastore.

Answer (score 1):

As previously answered, it's not possible to infer a cursor from a key because a cursor is tied to a query.  You can however, filter your queries by key.  E.g. select * from Task where **key** > Key(Task, 'sampleTask')